# Illustration for code presentation

Tags: image, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, presentation

I got an odd request, and I fear it will be closed as off-topic. So be it, but it's worth a shot.

I'm creating a presentation about dependency injection and inversion of control, and I thought I'd make the point of interchangeable parts that serve a common purpose, but has different implementations, by showing an image I've seen before.

Basically the image is of a man or a woman, but the image is split up into four parts:

- Head
- Torso
- uhm... not sure the name of this part, stomach, etc.
- Legs
- Possibly a fifth with feet

and for each part you can choose among a few variants, creating odd people in the process. ie. a man torso with a woman head.

But, I can't find such an image now of course. Does anyone know of such an image and can provide me with an url?

Comment: Personally, I'm more interested in the presentation - I'm trying to pull together a similar presentation for my company.

Comment: The presentation is currently in norwegian, I can see about publishing a translated version once I have presented it. It's fairly informal and not bogging into details so I've taken some shortcuts.

Comment: The middle section might best be described as "torso" and where you have torso you might want chest... looking for your image

Comment: The middle section is often called the "Trunk"

Comment: Ah, ok, so I got them wrong, ok.

Comment: "Abdomen" may be the word you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the stomach would be included in the torso (unless you are distinguishing the inside from the outside).  I'd make "arms" the fourth part.

As for illustrations, there are "build your own character" web apps to create both Simpson and South Park characters (and probably lot of others).  You could try one of those.

Comment: Thanks for that hint, allowed me to make my own simpsons character lookalike for the cover sheet, but wasn't quite what I had in mind. I'll try to find other such sites.